# Ajaxtoolkit Calendar Extender to show only one month dates:

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, gridview, calendarextender

I have one GridView called "gvDate" which has 12 columns such as January, Febuary, March, ..... and so on upto December. I have one Button called "btnAddNew" which would add one new row to the GridView "gvDate"

My GridView Columns are like this:

```
<Columns>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="April">
     <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:TextBox ID="txtApr" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("April")%>' contentEditable="false" Width="65px" Font-Size="Smaller"></asp:TextBox>
         <ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="AjaxAprCal" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtApr" Format="dd MMM yyyy" PopupButtonID="AprImg" PopupPosition="BottomRight" CssClass="custom-calendar">
         </ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender>
         <asp:ImageButton ID="AprImg" runat="server" ImageUrl="../App_Themes/RIBO/Images/calendar.png" />
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
.........
.........
.........
</Columns>
```

Likewise I have 12 columns in the GridView.

After adding the New Row, I need to select the date for the corresponding month. But the Calendar Extender only show the dates of the corresponding month only. It should not show the next or before or some other month dates.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have downloaded the AjaxControlToolkit 4.1.50731. In this version, the CalendarExtender has properties such as StartDate and EndDate. So this has solved my problem. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

```
Change Format="dd MMM yyyy" to Format="dd/MM/yyyy"
```